# How to turn off hover if on click event is active in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I have an icon name `tag-icon-arrow` i have onclick and hover events on it.

But since i hover over the icon the hover is active and when clicked both are active which i don't want, I know before clicking it will hover here,but if i click on the icon it should turn off.

```
 bindViewEvents: function () {
            let me = this
                , window = this.$window
                , $tagArrow = window.find(".tag-icon-arrow");

            $tagArrow.off().on('click', function (e) {
                me.highlight(e, true, true);
            });

            $tagArrow.hover(
                function (e) {me.highlight(e, true);},
                function (e) {me.highlight(e, false);}
            );
            $tagArrow.on('click', function (e) {
                me.selectRole(e);
            });

        },
selectRole: function (e) {
            let me = this;
            let $target = $(e.currentTarget);
            let hasRole = $target.is("[data-role]");
            let tagid = hasRole ? $target.attr("data-tagid") : null;
            me.api.xyz(tagid);
        },
        highlight: function (e, canHighlight, clicked) {
            let me = this
                , $target = $(e.currentTarget)
                , _id = $target.attr('data-id')
                , tagid = $target.attr("data-tagid")
                , tbId = me.isZone ? $target.attr("data-M") : "";

            if (canHighlight) {
                clicked ? $target.addClass("active") : 
                $target.removeClass("active");
                if (tbId === undefined) tbId = "";
                let objData = [{"_id": _id, "tagid": tagid,}];
                Common.Gateway.onEventsToXYZ({
                    "event": "xyz",
                    "fids": me.isZone ? [] : objData,
                    "rids": me.isZone ? objData : []
                });
                me.api.xyz(tagid);
            } else {
                if ($target.is(".active"))
                    return;
                Common.Gateway.onEventsToXYZ({
                    "event": "xyz"
                });
                me.api.xyz(null);
                $target.removeClass("active");
            }
        },
```

selectRole and highLight functions are custom functions to call based on the event triggered.
How can improve this so that both work properly? as they are expected to.

Comment: What exactly does `highlight()` and `selectRole()` do and why is `highlight()` called twice on a "hover" event? Also, the `.off()` method requires that you pass at least the event you want to remove, but you are passing nothing.

Comment: @zer00ne everything you've described is a valid jquery code. refer to the qjuery docs

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev OK, I did and I can't find those methods [`selectRole()`](https://jquery.com/?s=selectrole) or [`highlight()`](https://jquery.com/?s=highlight)

Comment: @zer00ne it was about "why is highlight() called twice on a "hover" event? Also, the .off() method requires that you pass at least the event you want to remove"

Comment: @zer00ne highlight and selectRole are two custom functions,which we perform on certain events,i should have added that my bad.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev you are stating that everything is valid jQuery code as a reply to my first comment: *"What exactly does highlight() and selectRole() do and why is highlight() called twice on a "hover" event?"*  Where do you see anywhere within that question did I say that the code was invalid? And how does referring to the jQuery docs going to answer any of those questions. My questions were directed to the OP in which he/she/it is best qualified to answer. BTW, I explained that `.off()` requires an event parameter of which the OP does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't turn off highlighting when the role is selected:

```js
const view = new function() { // I guess this is an angularjs controller
  
  const self = Object.assign(this /* $scope */, {highlight, bindViewEvents, selectRole});
  
  self.bindViewEvents();
  
  function highlight(e, val = true){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('highlighted', val);
  }

  function selectRole(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('selected');
  }

  function bindViewEvents() {
    
    const $tagArrow = $('.tag-icon-arrow');

    $tagArrow
      .hover(
        e => self.highlight(e), 
        e => $tagArrow.is('.selected') || self.highlight(e, false)
      )
      .on('click', e => self.selectRole(e));

  }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:50px;
}
.tag-icon-arrow{
  padding:20px 30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:#bbb;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.tag-icon-arrow.highlighted{
  background:#ffddee;
}
.tag-icon-arrow.selected{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tag-icon-arrow">Hover & click me</a>
```

But better use CSS:

```js
const view = new function() { // I guess this is an angularjs controller
  
  const self = Object.assign(this /* $scope */, {bindViewEvents, selectRole});
  
  self.bindViewEvents();
  
  function selectRole(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('selected');
  }

  function bindViewEvents() {
    
    const $tagArrow = $('.tag-icon-arrow');

    $tagArrow
      .on('click', e => self.selectRole(e));

  }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:50px;
}
.tag-icon-arrow{
  padding:20px 30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:#bbb;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.tag-icon-arrow:hover,.tag-icon-arrow.selected{
  background:#ffddee;
}
.tag-icon-arrow.selected{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tag-icon-arrow">Hover & click me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my mistake its not an angular controller its an BackboneJS controller(idk if they're same), but your logic is pretty much correct here.

Comment: @SDP you are welcome :) if you find my answer useful you could accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up). that way i'll be rewarded with points and will be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: @SDP should work, just copy the body of the `bindViewEvents` to your `bindViewEvents` and change `self` to `this`. and make sure you toggle `selected` class in `selectRole()`

Comment: Thank you it actually worked in a weird way since i never knew i can do $any.hover().on(). worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a flag that says whether the icon has been clicked or not, and then use that flag to conditionally turn on/off the hover effect.

Here's the code:

```js
    bindViewEvents: function () {
      let me = this
        , window = this.$window
        , $tagArrow = window.find(".tag-icon-arrow")
        , clicked = false;
    
      $tagArrow.off().on('click', function (e) {
        me.highlight(e, true, true);
        clicked = true;
      });
    
      $tagArrow.hover(
        function (e) {
          if (!clicked) {
            me.highlight(e, true);
          }
        },
        function (e) {
          if (!clicked) {
            me.highlight(e, false);
          }
        }
      );
    
      $tagArrow.on('click', function (e) {
        me.selectRole(e);
        clicked = true;
      });
    },
```